# Whole image is not rendered?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm new to Blender. I have version 2.90 and I made my first model but when I press **F12** to render, it renders only half of the image not the whole image.

Is there any way to fix this?

This is the actual image:

[image: the actual image]

This is what it looks like after render:

[image: what it looks like after render]

I hadn't touch my settings. Everything is  default settings...

Anyone know why it happens?   Thanks! in advance hope you will find the answer>>

Answer (score 2):

This is what it is supposed to happen.
The first image in the question is not the camera view, but the perspective view in the viewport.

You see the small box with a filled black triangle on the left? That's your **Camera**, and your picture will be whatever the Camera sees. That's what you render out. You need to switch to your camera view. Click the small camera symbol in the right side of the viewport to go into camera view, or press <kbd>Numpad Period</kbd>

[image]

Then change the **Rotation and Location** of the camera to frame the desired picture.

Comment: Can I zoom in or out in my camera perspective?

Comment: if you specifically want a picture from the back side then you can zoom out by moving back by clicking G > Z > Z to move backwards